# SOAP UI How to pass Teardown script "Pass" or "Fail" status to Octopus to fail a Deployment?

Tags: powershell, groovy, soapui

I am trying to have a status like failed  or pass to be passed to Octopus to fail or pass a deployment.

I have three different projects, one project per product. Each of these tests are run today on the server using batch scripts. I am trying to work on a solution using powershell script, which will invoke these tests as batch and if the test results fail pass a variable and value back to Octopus to fail  our deployment. We do not want our code to deploy in stage if tests fail.

I have bunch of scripts I am trying, like get Exitcode, but nothing seems to be working. I have the Scripts working if I kick off the .ps1 on the server. But I need the ability to pass fail or pass status to Octopus. can someone please help?

Comment: so your tests do not exit with non zero exit code if they fail?

Comment: yes.  I am not getting a value into $LastExitCode

code sample below 

$exitCode = 0 # Default to success

# Pretend that this is happening in your loop of scripts to run.
Clear-Host
    # Run a script
   start-process "cmd.exe" "/c E:\SoapUI\RunTests\RunFunctionalTests.bat" 
   Write-Host "The Exit code from Batch1 is " $LastExitCode
    # Check the output
    $LASTEXITCODE = 0 # This one passed!
    if($LASTEXITCODE -gt $exitCode) {
        $exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
    }

Comment: I know testrunner.bat should return exit codes based on the success or failure, not sure how to get that to return. I am using this Pass or Fail status to fail Octopus Deployment. Wondering if I should do in groovy script/tear down script instead? Can someone has a solution for the same.

Comment: maybe your bat file swallows exit code?

Comment: oh wait, i think you overwrite it with your check, it should be something like: `exit $lastexitcode`. this will just exit with whatever the exit code is. i can convert this to an answer if this helps you, i'm just not sude what you are doing exactly, if you want to check you can do: `if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) { exit $lastexitcode }`

Comment: May be this helps. I have different test suites I run per release. I am trying to automate these tests via Octopus. We dont have Jenkins for the time being. So trying to build Powershell scripts to execute the tests using testrunner.bat command line. These tests are currently running as batch scripts on the server. I want to automate this via Octopus tool. So an extra step is after the tests gets kicked off from Octopus, we need to send some kind of status back to Octopus for the tests Pass/Fail condition. If the tests Pass- Deployment is successful if Fail then fail deployment and rolbackcode

Comment: i dont understand. where is the question. you can use $lastexitcode variable to get exit code. if your bat files returns wrong exit code, fix your bat file

Comment: The $lastexitcode is coming as empty like this $lastexitcode=

Comment: ok, i have no idea what is wrong with your scripts. guess what. you didnt even post them. you said it works if you launch ps1 manually. there is absolutely no difference if you launch it or octopus does

Comment: I posted in my first comment?

Comment: i dont know? first of all, you should post it in the question, because its unreadable in the comment. second, you didnt post your bat file code